# Switched loop. Why?

Tags: electrical

[image]

I have this set up whereby the white is always hot and the black wire is on hot in an unstitched (off) position.  I understand it is called a “switched loop”.  I don’t understand this.

I discovered this when I was going to feed power to a new receptacle and found that the white wire was hot (line).

Why would this set up be done in the first place? Both switch and light are original to the house?

Why would the circuit terminus be at the switch?

If the switch “disconnects” the power to the light, because there is always power to the light, then why not change the light switch connection and bring the power to the light switch and use the proper colored wires?

Comment: It saved an extra unneeded copper wire.  Before smart switches, neutrals were not needed at switches.  When white wires are used this way, they are supposed to be marked black or red.  It is mainly a cost benefit, if power is already in the ceiling, why use another cable that is not needed.  These days you must use a black, red and white wire cable to switches.  If you never use a smart switch the white wire(neutral) is just wasted in the switch box.  Look where the light is.  To bring power to the switch you need to run a cable to the switch and then run another cable the same length back.

Comment: Does it work ? YES ! leave it alone

Comment: Not really a DIY question ... switch loops save time and money during installation especially for an upper floor with an unfinished attic.  Simply, it's harder to run unswitched power from one place to another if they are both half way up a wall.  Think like a construction manager not a circuit diagram.

Comment: Also, the reason that white is used for unswitched hot is so that at the load (light, outlet, etc.), you don’t have two white wires connected. Instead, you have black (switched hot, from the loop) and white (neutral back to the source).

Comment: Minor terminology detail: 'switch loop

Comment: Is there a green screw on the switch?  Being in a plastic box the ground(bare) wire is usually attached to a switch/receptacle/light ground screw.

Answer (score 2):

In ye olden times:

- Switch boxes generally did not need neutral. Occasionally for timers, but not for much else. Motion sensors were not common in residential applications, smart switches and WiFi simply didn't exist.
- If your cables run mostly in the ceiling, a switch loop allows you to run hot and neutral to the fixture box and hot and switched hot to the switch. The neutral never needs to go down to the switch.
- This saves a little bit of labor (fewer connections) and means that nearly all 15A and 20A 120V circuits in a house can be wired entirely with /2 cable instead of /3 cable, saving using (and stocking) another type of cable and the /2 cable is always cheaper than the equivalent /3 cable.

And last, but not least, there is no *proper colored wires* in the US system, at least with cables. The wire colors are:

- Green or bare is always ground
- Black, red, blue, orange, yellow, etc. is always *some type* of hot - but that can be hot, switched hot, traveler in a 3-way circuit, etc.
- White is neutral *wherever there is a neutral*. So if you have hot and neutral or switched hot and neutral, the white wire will be the neutral. But white can also be:

  - Hot in a switch loop
  - 2nd hot in a 240V-only circuit (e.g., water heater or simple cooktop)
  - Traveler (depending on configuration, a /3 in a 3-way circuit can be two travelers + hot, two travelers + switched hot or two travelers + neutral - only in "two travelers + neutral" is the white wire neutral)

If you have conduit and individual wires then white is *always* neutral. But that is not common except in New York City and a few other places. For most people is cables, and a /2 cable is always black & white and a /3 cable is always black, red & white.

You *can* do your own marking with tape. That is required (but often ignored or lost) on switch loop white wires. But you can also add markings to label wires as if they are particular colors. Which means neutral is always white (but white is not always neutral) and:

- Black - Hot
- Red - Switched Hot (which is "natural" if you have a modern switch with a /3 from the switch to the light fixture)
- Yellow - Travelers

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It's often easier to deliver always-hot and neutral power to the lamp rather than the switch.  Since dumb switches are mechanical and do not require any electrical power for their own needs, there is no need to bring "power" (as in hot and neutral).  They only need to bring always-hot and switched-hot, and it's cheaper to just use /2 cable and re-task the white wire.

Hence the "switch loop".

You, like many people, want actual power at the switch (hot and neutral). Most people want that for motion sensors, smart switches "hey alexa" etc. However you want it for a receptacle.   Because of the popularity of smart switches, NEC 2011 outlawed the classic switch loop in most cases. Now, when power arrives at the light, you must use /3+gnd cable for a "switch loop", providing black for always-hot, red for switched-hot and white for neutral.  You will not see this in your house; any black-white-red switch wiring will be 3-way switches (which are complicated).